# Is Mesos master needed if we use Chronos?

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, mesos-chronos

Let's say I have 1 Chronos machine, 1 Mesos master running on another machine and Mesos slave running on yet a different machine (total 3 machines).

If I stop the Mesos master, will the Mesos slave still continue working (and take up more tasks in future for execution) and will Chronos behave like a master for the Mesos slave or is Mesos master always needed?

+1 for some documentation link for understanding Chronos-Mesos interaction deeply and clearly. Thanks a ton in advance.

1 more quick question: if Mesos slave is stopped, will Mesos master perform the slave functions as well (I mean the task execution)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I stop the mesos master, will the mesos slave still continue working

**Yes**, scheduled tasks will not be killed and works normally but Chronos will not be notified about their state

> and take up more tasks in future for execution

**No**, without Master chronos can't getn information about tasks state and schedule new tasks — it talks only with Master.

> will chronos behave like a master for the mesos slave or mesos master is always needed ?

**Mesos Master is always needed.**

> If mesos slave is stopped, will mesos master perform the slave functinos as well (I mean the task execution)

**No**. Master only delegates tasks to agents it does not execute them.

This concept is described in [Mesos Architecure](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/architecture/) and [framework guide](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/high-availability-framework-guide/)

Comment: thanks, buddy. that was a point to point answer. Will go through those docs minutely